# Better option to "where to declare actions?(oop)"

Tags: oop

Doubt about **where to define the actions** that are going to **act on attributes of one class**?
Ex:-**Account** is a **class** where we going to define attributes of account like account no,holder name.
As usual **Employee(class)** of the Bank can add,update(crud) operation on customer's account.
My doubt is in which class we have to define those (crud)actions either in Employee class or in Account class?.
Because these operations are performed by employee in real time.On the other hand,Actions need to act on Account attributes may define in Account class itself,which is the better one?
**'Actions need to be performed on  attributes ,defined in same class is better' or 'Actions are defined in class with respect to whose actions are they(actors) is better'**?

Comment: OP is not looking for examples which demonstrate ways to address his specific question, which makes this question way too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding of the problem you describe, such "operations" go in the [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).

You can see in the link I shared above that Martin Fowler describes the service layer as:

> Defines an application's boundary with a layer of services that
>   establishes a set of available **operations** and coordinates the
>   application's response in each operation.

So, in my view of your solution, both Employee and Account are just POJOs like @Rotka said. In my view the interfaces for your layers would be somewhat like

At the data source layer:

```
interface AccountRepository {
  Account findById(Long id);
  Account save(Account account);
}
```

And I doubt that you can delete a bank account, you could put it a state of inactivity though.

Than your service layer could be somewhat like

```
interface AccountService {
   Account openAccount(Account account);
   void closeAccount(Account account);
   transferFunds(Account source, Account target);
   ...
}
```

What you call employee is probably the wrong abstraction to use here. You probably think in terms of users, like is the current user allowed to open accounts?

So, consider the following hypothetical implementation

```
class DefaultAccountService implements AccountService {

   private SecurityContext securityContext;
   private Validator validator;
   private AccountRespotiroy accountRepository;

   @Override
   public Account openAccount(Account account) {
     if(!securityContext.getUser().hasPermission("openAccount")){
        throw new UnAuthorizedException("You cannot open accounts");
     }
     Set<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(account);
     if(violations.size() > 0){
        throw new BadRequestException("Invalid account", violations);
     }
     return accountRepository.save(account);
   }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO , Employee class should be a simple POJO , in order to use it in other components , and you should create an AccountOperation Service (an EJB in Java EE context)

```
    public class AccountOperation 
   {

        Customer customer;
        Employee employee;
        public void createAnAccount(){

        }

        public void deleteAnAccount(){

        }

        public void debitAnAccount(){       
        }

    }
```

Comment: indeed , Pojo's should remain simple to be reusable potentialy in other contexts (other projects maybe) , nevertheless , sometimes for educational purpose we tend to include operations within Pojo classes just to highlight OOP concepts to students . but in real projects it's definetly not a good practise.

Answer (score -1):

For creating and deleting an account - create an instance of the account, and then pass the "whodunnit" as the employee - or some related identifier when something is done:

```
Account Account = new Account(Customer, AccountNumber);
Account.createAccount(Employee).
Account.deleteAccount(Employee).
```

For transactions you need two accounts - the credit and debit account. Because a transaction spans multiple accounts, the following method needs to be in it's own class:

```
public void AccountTransaction(Account CreditAccount, 
                               Account DebitAccount, 
                               float TransactionAmount.
                               Employee Employee){

   CreditAccount.creditAccount(TransactionAmount, Employee);
   DebitAccount.debitAccount(TransactionAmount, Employee);
   }
```

most likely this method would be called by a number of "transaction types" (loan, interest payment, money transfer, etc.)

Comment: There is many ways to implement this functionalities.I need concept ,"we can define function wherever class we want",But which one gives more meaning as point of OOP.

Comment: I provided examples which implement actual concepts - if you're looking for a dissertation on OO concepts instead of using Google and reading the blogs on the subject, then you've come to the wrong place.